# Matlab fir1 function error

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I'm running Matlab 2014a on Linux and trying to apply a simple FIR filter using the fir1 function.  I keep getting the following error, no matter how I try to build the filter:

```
>>fir1(15,[0.1])
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

>>Error in firls (line 80)
    cos_ints = [omega; sin((1:N)' * omega)];

>>Error in fir1 (line 121)
    hh = firls(L-1,ff,aa);
```

I've used the debugger to go to the line of code, and it looks like it's always trying to multiply a column vector of length(order), (1:N)', by another column vector, omega.  This doesn't make any sense.  Is the fir1 function broken, or am I doing something wrong?  This error occurs for me even if I try to run the examples given by MathWorks.

Comment: have you tried the second input argument without the squared brackets? E.g. `fir1(15,0.1)`. Unfortunately with `MATLAB Version: 8.1.0.604 (R2013a)` I cannot reproduce the error. For me, both `fir1(15,0.1)` and `fir1(15,[0.1])` work.

Comment: It also works in R2010b

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that Matlab's `firls` function is masked by another function of the same name, which is in Matlab's path and therefore gets called from `fir1`.

What do you get when you type :

> which firls

? - You should get something which ends in `\toolbox\signal\signal\firls.m`